# Depth peeling and antialiasing

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to implement depth peeling in OpenGL, but I can't make it work with MSAA.

Resolving the depth texture and using it in shader didn't work as I expected. The best result I got so far was fetching depth from a multisample texture like this, but when my scene contains thin lines they still look weird:

[image: scene example]

```c
    const int samples = 4;
    float fragmentDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
    for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
    {
        float texelPreviousDepth = texelFetch(previousLayerDepth, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), i).x;
        if (fragmentDepth <= texelPreviousDepth + depthComparisonDelta)
            discard;
    }
```

I have been told that depth peeling is probably not compatible with MSAA and I need to implement antialiasing by hand. So is it possible to use MSAA in my case and if not, what would you recommend instead?